# Regex negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to modify this regex

```
href=\"(.*)\"
```

which matches this...

```
href="./pothole_locator_map.aspx?lang=en-gb&lat=53.153977&lng=-3.533306"
```

To NOT match this...

```
href="./pothole_locator_map.aspx?lang=en-gb&lat=53.153977&lng=-3.533306&returnurl=AbandonedVehicles.aspx"
```

Tried this, but with no luck

```
href=\"(.*)\"(?!&returnurl=AbandonedVehicles.aspx)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Al.

Comment: URL parameters aren't ordered, so you have to be able to deal with `/pothole_locator_map.aspx?lang=en-gb&returnurl=AbandonedVehicles.aspx&lat=53.153977&lng=-3.533306` and other variations, too. Why not just check for the existence of the GET parameter "returnurl"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lookaheads should be placed before the string is consumed by matching, i.e.

```
href=\"(?!.*&returnurl=AbandonedVehicles\.aspx)(.*)\"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
href="(?!.*returnurl=AbandonedVehicles\.aspx)(.*)"
```